# App freeze after launch

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I got a test app in Flight Test but this App just freeze when I opened. However, when I used xcode with my device, the app was working fine.

What should I do?

Comment: When does it freeze? On the loading screen?

Comment: What are you doing in viewDidLoad etc? Does it freeze immediately?

Comment: The first page doesn't have a ViewController. And freezes inmediately

Comment: Would you mind editing your question with some code? It's not possible to debug a problem like this without knowing a bit about what your code is doing when it freezes.

Comment: Also maybe just upload the project to TestFlight with a different build number to see if the problem persists